# Morton Code sort gives the wrong coordinates

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, photoshop-script

For the past few days I've been trying to procedurally piece together a bunch of small tiles that are sorted using Morton code. I got most of the script to work with a 4x4 test, but for whatever reason the image is slightly offset on the Y axis the further right it goes. I'm not sure how to fix this, I'm not really an expert on bitwise operators but maybe it has something to do with that?

Here's the code:

```js
var fileDirectory = Folder.selectDialog("Select a folder");
var files = fileDirectory.getFiles("*.png");
var activeDoc = app.activeDocument;
var scale = 4;

var MASKS = [0x55555555, 0x33333333, 0x0F0F0F0F, 0x00FF00FF];
var SHIFTS = [1, 2, 4, 8];

for (var fileIdx = 0; fileIdx < files.length; fileIdx++)
{
   app.load(files[fileIdx]);
   backFile = app.activeDocument;
   backFile.selection.selectAll();
   backFile.selection.copy();
   backFile.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
   activeDoc.paste();
   activeDoc.activeLayer.name = fileIdx;
   
   var x = fileIdx % scale;
   var y = fileIdx / scale;
   
    x = (x | (x << SHIFTS[3])) & MASKS[3];
    x = (x | (x << SHIFTS[2])) & MASKS[2];
    x = (x | (x << SHIFTS[1])) & MASKS[1];
    x = (x | (x << SHIFTS[0])) & MASKS[0];

    y = (y | (y << SHIFTS[3])) & MASKS[3];
    y = (y | (y << SHIFTS[2])) & MASKS[2];
    y = (y | (y << SHIFTS[1])) & MASKS[1];
    y = (y | (y << SHIFTS[0])) & MASKS[0];
    
    var id = x | (y << 1);
    
    x = (id % scale) * 256;
    y = (id / scale) * 256;
    
    var LB = activeDoc.activeLayer.bounds;
    activeDoc.activeLayer.translate(-LB[0].as('px') + new UnitValue(x, 'px'), -LB[1].as('px') + new UnitValue(y, 'px'));
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear (at least to me) what the actual end goal is, nor the function of the `app` class, but one potential issue is with the iteration of over the length of the file.  If `files[fileIdx]` refers to a single character, then that's only 8 bits, whereas all the masks are 32 bits.  Presumably there is a need to handle 4 bytes of the file at a time, thereby representing a 32 bit unsigned integer (endinan-ness will matter), but again, the question is lacking quite a bit of context to provide a proper answer...

Comment: @Trentium The purpose of `app.load(files[fileIdx])` is to load a file from an array of file paths into a new open document. The program then takes that image and copies it into the main document.

Comment: So if `fileIdx` is an index into a list of files, why does the program shortly thereafter use this index to set the variables `x` and `y`?  Seems like you need another loop to iterate through the contents of the file itself, but again, not totally clear what is attempting to be accomplished...

Comment: The Morton code is the same as the one [here](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#InterleaveBMN).  The only difference is what you are doing to x and y at the start and end of the loop. From a Photoshop point of view, what size is the canvas of the source document and images that you are loading in?